# Quickest way to test whether array is constant

Tags: performance-tuning, list-manipulation

At the moment I use `Length[ DeleteDuplicates[ array ] ] == 1` to check whether an array is constant, but I'm not sure whether this is optimal.

What would be the quickest way to test whether an array consists of equal elements?

What if the elements would be integers?

What if they are floats?

Comment: `Equal@@MinMax[array]` might be a bit faster...

Comment: Your `Length[ DeleteDuplicates[ array ] ] == 1` does not test whether `array` is constant but rather whether its rows are equal. This is equivalent to `Equal @@ array`. To test whether `array` is constant you could use `Equal @@ Flatten[array]`

Comment: @Henrik has a good idea but "duplicate" and "equal" mean different things in Mathematica, especially for floating-point numbers and expressions like `array = {1 + Sqrt[3], Sqrt[4 + 2 Sqrt[3]]}`.  An alternative to check duplicates is `0 == Subtract @@ MinMax[array]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Good point. Admittedly, I had only the (machine) integer case in mind.

Comment: What is the maximum depth of your arrays?  `Length[DeleteDuplicates[array]]` assumes it's depth 1 (a "flat" or non-nested list).  `MinMax[array]` will work with arrays of any depth (vectors, matrices, tensors...).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I suspect the OP neglected the point because of the use of `DeleteDuplicates` and the question about "equal elements."  I raised it, so that OP might clarify which criterion is desired. (One might want to use `Chop` or `Threshold` on `max - min` in the case of floats depending on how `array` is calculated.)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher You should add the MinMax approach as an answer, it is faster than the other answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are two methods that are quite fast for flat lists (you can flatten arrays to test at deeper levels):

```
const = ConstantArray[1, 100000];
nonconst = Append[const, 2];
```

Using `CountDistinct` (or `CountDistinctBy`):

```
CountDistinct[const] === 1
CountDistinct[nonconst] === 1
```

> True

> False

Based on pattern matching:

```
MatchQ[const, {Repeated[x_]}]
MatchQ[nonconst , {Repeated[x_]}]
```

> True

> False

The `MatchQ` approach can be generalized for deeper arrays using `Level` without having to `Flatten` everything:

```
constTensor = ConstantArray[1, {5, 5, 5}];
MatchQ[Level[constTensor, {ArrayDepth[constTensor]}], {Repeated[x_]}]
```

> True

`Level` doesn't always perform better than `Flatten`, though. `Flatten` seems very efficient for packed arrays.

## Timings

```
CountDistinct[const] // RepeatedTiming
MatchQ[const, {Repeated[x_]}] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.00021, 1}

> {0.0051, True}

`MatchQ` has the advantage that it short-circuits when a list doesn't match:

```
nonconst2 = Prepend[const, 2];
MatchQ[nonconst2, {Repeated[x_]}] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {6.*10^-7, False}

## Edit

Here's another method I just came up with. It avoids messing around with the array (flattening etc.):

```
constantArrayQ[arr_] := Block[{
   depth = ArrayDepth[arr],
   fst
  },
   fst = Extract[arr, ConstantArray[1, depth]];
   FreeQ[arr, Except[fst], {depth}, Heads -> False]
];
```

It seems like this one is quite fast for unpacked arrays:

```
constTensor = ConstantArray[1, 400*{1, 1, 1}];
constTensor[[1, 1, 1]] = 2.;
<< Developer`
PackedArrayQ @ constTensor
(* False *)


MatchQ[Level[constTensor, {ArrayDepth[constTensor]}], {Repeated[x_]}] // AbsoluteTiming
MatchQ[Flatten[constTensor], {Repeated[x_]}] // AbsoluteTiming
constantArrayQ[constTensor] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.54311, False} *)
(* {2.20663, False} *)
(* {0.0236709, False} *)
```

For packed arrays, it looks like `MatchQ[Flatten[constTensor], {Repeated[x_]}]` is actually the fastest:

```
constTensor = ConstantArray[1, 400*{1, 1, 1}];
constTensor[[1, 1, 1]] = 2;
<< Developer`
PackedArrayQ @ constTensor
(* True *)


MatchQ[Level[constTensor, {ArrayDepth[constTensor]}], {Repeated[x_]}] // AbsoluteTiming
MatchQ[Flatten[constTensor], {Repeated[x_]}] // AbsoluteTiming
constantArrayQ[constTensor] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.76109, False} *)
(* {0.19088, False} *)
(* {1.17001, False} *)
```

Comment: Unexpectedly, `MatchQ` doesn't check the last bit on machine floats: `MatchQ[Table[1. + k*$MachineEpsilon, {k, 2}], {Repeated[x_]}]`. Timings?

Answer (score 9):

`` Statistics`Library`ConstantVectorQ `` is quite fast.

Using Sjoerd's input examples:

```
const = ConstantArray[1, 100000];
nonconst = Append[const, 2];
nonconst2 = Prepend[const, 2];


t11 = Statistics`Library`ConstantVectorQ@const // RepeatedTiming;
t21 = CountDistinct[const] == 1 // RepeatedTiming;
t31 = MatchQ[const, {Repeated[x_]}] // RepeatedTiming;
t41 = Length[DeleteDuplicates@const] == 1 // RepeatedTiming;
t51 = Equal @@ MinMax[const] // RepeatedTiming;
t61 = Equal @@ const // RepeatedTiming;

t12 = Statistics`Library`ConstantVectorQ@nonconst // RepeatedTiming
t22 = CountDistinct[nonconst] == 1 // RepeatedTiming;
t32 = MatchQ[nonconst, {Repeated[x_]}] // RepeatedTiming;
t42 = Length[DeleteDuplicates@nonconst] == 1 // RepeatedTiming;
t52 = Equal @@ MinMax[nonconst] // RepeatedTiming;
t62 = Equal @@ nonconst // RepeatedTiming;

t13 = Statistics`Library`ConstantVectorQ@nonconst2 // RepeatedTiming
t23 = CountDistinct[nonconst2] == 1 // RepeatedTiming;
t33 = MatchQ[nonconst2, {Repeated[x_]}] // RepeatedTiming;
t43 = Length[DeleteDuplicates@nonconst2] == 1 // RepeatedTiming;
t53 = Equal @@ MinMax[nonconst2] // RepeatedTiming;
t63 = Equal @@ nonconst2 // RepeatedTiming;


TableForm[{{t11, t12, t13}, {t21, t22, t23}, {t31, t32, t33}, {t41, 
   t42, t43}, {t51, t52, t53}, {t61, t62, t63}}, 
 TableHeadings -> {{"ConstantVectorQ", "CountDistinct", "MatchQ", 
    "Length+DeleteDuplicates", "Equal + MinMax", "Apply[Equal]"}, 
    {"const", "nonconst", "nonconst2"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know who wrote ``Statistics`Library`` but it's full of good stuff. (+1)

Comment: Why is `CountDistinct@const` so much faster than `Equal@@const` or `SameQ@@const`? That seems counterintutive.

Comment: Oh, nice find there

Comment: @Alan It's because the array is "unpacked".  Start with ``const = Developer`FromPackedArray@ConstantArray[1, 100000];`` and rerun the timings; then `Equal @@ const` is only about twice as slow.  See [What is a packed array?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array)

Comment: @Alan, the difference may also have to do with the fact that  `CountDistinct`  uses `Length[DeleteDuplicates @ const] == 1` under the hood.

Comment: @kglr This still seems odd to me. `DeleteDuplicates` should require comparison and deletion, while `SameQ` should only require comparison. Perhaps `SameQ` is doing all pairwise comparisons in order not to assume transitivity of the comparisons?

Comment: @Alan `SameQ @@ array` is a little faster than `DeleteDuplicates[array]` on `array = Sqrt@ConstantArray[2, {100000}];`. The reason `DeleteDuplicates` is faster on `array = ConstantArray[2, {100000}];` is that in effect it computes ``DeleteDuplicates[Developer`ToPackedArray@array]`` and `SameQ @@ array` cannot take advantage of packed arrays. Numbers have certain optimizations available that general expressions do not. Data functions such as `DeleteDuplicates` are programmed to take advantage of them.

Comment: @MichaelE2 OK, that makes sense. Clearly I've paid too little attention to when arrays are packed and unpacked. Can you recommend useful documentation?

Comment: @Alan The Q&A I linked is probably the best discussion available.  The closest to official documentation is this Wolfram Library notebook and article by one of the lead kernel developers, https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/391/, which is also linked in a comment to that Q&A.

Answer (score 6):

`Equal@@MinMax[array]` might be quite fast if `array` is a packed list of integers. But it cannot short-circuit like `` Statistics`Library`ConstantVectorQ `` does. And it is also not very robust with regard to (machine) floating point numbers: `Equal` and `SameQ` both use a certain tolerance for their equality checks (I forgot which precise one they use; I just recall that the tolerance of `SameQ` should be the lower one). This may or may not be the desired behavior in a particular application.

Comment: The tolerances are ``Internal`$EqualTolerance`` and ``Internal`$SameQTolerance`` for those who wish to change them.  For example, ``Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = 0}, Equal @@ MinMax[array]]``.