# Fastest way to check if array is zero

Tags: performance-tuning, list-manipulation

What is the fastest way to check if an entire array is zero? For my case the elements of the array are either 1 or 0 but for reference purposes the general case can also be considered.

Comment: You could use `Total`?

Comment: Maybe ``LinearAlgebra`Private`ZeroArrayQ``? I recall that we had a similar question not long ago...

Comment: Ah, here it is. Not a duplicate but related and thus maybe of interest: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/230971

Comment: @Q.P. - `Total@matrix` returns a vector rather than a scalar. Even if you `Flatten` the matrix first, you would also need to use `Abs` to ensure that a zero result indicated that the matrix was all zeroes.

Comment: @Q.P. `Total` would work but I'm interested in _speed_. It might be the fastest but I don't know.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`` LinearAlgebra`Private`ZeroArrayQ `` seems to do quite a good job. Curiously enough, `` Statistics`Library`ConstantVectorQ[#] && #[[1]] == 0 & `` tends to be a little bit faster on my machine.

Answer (score 4):

I tested the methods from Henrik and got the following timings

```
linAlgZeroArrayQ = LinearAlgebra`Private`ZeroArrayQ;
statZeroArrayQ = 
  Statistics`Library`ConstantVectorQ[#] && #[[1]] == 0 &;
totalZeroArrayQ = Total[#] == 0 &;

n = 10^5;
exactZeros = ConstantArray[0, n];
numericalZeros = ConstantArray[0., n];
exactSparse = exactZeros; exactSparse[[n/2]] = 1;
numericalSparse = numericalZeros; numericalSparse[[n/2]] = 1.;
exactRandom = RandomChoice[{0, 1}, n];
numericalRandom = RandomChoice[{0., 1.}, n];

functions = {linAlgZeroArrayQ, statZeroArrayQ, totalZeroArrayQ};
tests = {exactZeros, numericalZeros, exactSparse, numericalSparse, 
   exactRandom, numericalRandom};
results = Table[
   AbsoluteTiming[Do[functions[[j]]@tests[[i]], {10000}]][[1]], {i, 1,
     Length@tests}, {j, 1, Length@functions}
   ];

TableForm[results, 
 TableHeadings -> {{"Exact zeros", "Numerical zeros", "Exact sparse", 
    "Numerical sparse", "Exact random", 
    "Numerical random"}, {"Linear Algebra method", 
    "Statistics method", "Total"}}]
```

[image]

For the cases I tested the `` LinearAlgebra`Private`ZeroArrayQ `` seems like a clear winner but there might be cases/machines where `` Statistics`Library`ConstantVectorQ[#] && #[[1]] == 0 & `` wins.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following

```
AA = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}};
AllTrue[Flatten[AA], PossibleZeroQ]
```